# Global styles in Angular 4 library

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm currently in the process of creating a component library for Angular 4 from an existing application. This is to give customers the option to extend and/or customize our application. A custom application is bootstrapped with our own `AppComponent` by default. Example:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent, AppModule } from '@app/core';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        AppModule
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ]
})
export class CustomModule { }
```

The `AppComponent` looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: "app",
    styleUrls: ['./../assets/scss/style.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    templateUrl: "./app.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {    

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }   

}
```

Note that the `ViewEncapsulation` is set to `None` to make the styles of this component global. This works as expected in the original application. However, as soon as you create a package from the application and install it as a dependency for a custom application, those styles are not being applied globally anymore. I can see them in the resulting `.js` files though, they're just not applied.

Excerpt from transpiled `.js` file:

```
var AppComponent = (function () {
    function AppComponent() {
    }
    /**
     * @return {?}
     */
    AppComponent.prototype.ngOnInit = function () {
    };
    return AppComponent;
}());
AppComponent.decorators = [
    { type: Component, args: [{
            selector: 'app',
            styles: ["GLOBAL_STYLES_ARE_HERE"],
            encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
            template: "<router-outlet></router-outlet>"
        },] },
];
```

Am I missing something here? Why are these styles not global when I use the `AppComponent` to bootstrap another application? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try the possibility of declaring you global styles under the `src` folder of your angular app?  Normally the styles added to this file are directly injected in your components and you won't have to manipulate the view encapsulation to add them to your components.

Comment: You mean the one you get when you scaffold an Angular application using the Angular CLI tool? Note that the global styles are inside the library package, not the application.

Comment: @KajNelissen Have you found a solution for this? I am also trying to achieve the same.